# how can i play youtube video with php like a proxy

Tags: php, youtube

this is site

www.proxfree.net

i live in pakistan. youtube blocked here. so i watch the youtube from this site

www.proxfree.net

kindly anybody php expert help me how can make a youtube watch script like proxfree.net. waiting for help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Do you expect others to do all the work? StackOverflow is not a request site but a help site. We'll help **fix** your code and tell you why it's wrong - we won't create it for you. You might as well ask "can anyone help me make Facebook?".

Comment: It would help us if you include information that you may have found, code attempts and similar.

Comment: It is _much_ easier to set up any package _designed to actually proxy_ (Apache itself could do it, I've dabbled with some Squid, but there are loads out there, take your pick).

Comment: Your solution site [PlayNow.pk](http://www.playnow.pk/) You can search, play or download all youtube videos here.

Answer (score 1):

In short (since this question doesn't deserve any better answer as it shows absolutely no effort):

- Rent a server in a country that doesn't block YouTube
- Make sure the webhost allows proxy-like functionality
- Create a form you'll use to input the external website URL
- Use cURL to communicate with that external website

There are **tons** of resources about this. Here's one: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-online-proxy-server-minutes/

Comment: Why even bother to make one, when there are so many out there? It's like those `*book.com`, or `*space.com` pages that appear all the time, imitating the obvious social networks.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos I completely agree, I just tried to answer the question directly, maybe it's really about making a proxy. But with that effort, I guess we'll never know...